# How do I pipe Java exceptions into a text file along with normal output?

Tags: java, command-line, console, logging, pipe

When I use batchfile.bat >> logfile.txt command in the Windows commandline, it correctly outputs the normal output into the text file, but the Java exceptions get output to the console. Can I make it so that exceptions are written to log file as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java exceptions are printed on the standard error stream.

To pipe the standard error stream (file descriptor 2) into a file you can do:

```
batchfile.bat 2>> errorlog.txt
```

To pipe both standard error and standard out into the same file:

```
batchfile.bat >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

You can do the same on Unix and Windows